# desired output not coming

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

```
double num1, num2, result;
String sign = "";


protected void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sign = "+";
    num1 = double.Parse(tb1.Text);
    tb1.Text = "";
}

protected void equal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        num2 = double.Parse(Convert.ToString(tb1.Text));
        if(sign.Equals("+")){
                result = num1 + num2;
                tb1.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
        }
         if(sign.Equals("-")){
                result = num1 - num2;
                tb1.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
        }
        if(sign.Equals("*")){
                result = num1 * num2;
                tb1.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
        }
        if(sign.Equals("/")){
                result = num1 / num2;
                tb1.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        tb1.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}

protected void minus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sign = "-";
    num1 = double.Parse(tb1.Text);
    tb1.Text = "";
}

protected void divide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sign = "/";
    num1 = double.Parse(tb1.Text);
    tb1.Text = "";
}

protected void product_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sign = "*";
    num1 = double.Parse(tb1.Text);
    tb1.Text = "";
}
```

this is my simple program which performs arithmetic operations, but when i click '=' button it does not gives me result instead it gives me the last number entered in the textfield..
anyone knows whats the problem with code?

Comment: @Habib - the OP is setting it here: `num2 = double.Parse(Convert.ToString(tb1.Text));`

Comment: @KarlAnderson, yup, missed that

Comment: no its been set in equal functin right after try block starting

Comment: Can't you put a break-point and check the values of the variables and flow of the code?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3):

Web applications are stateless, a new instance of your class is created for each request (GET or POST).

Therefore the fields in the class are reinitialized on every POST:

```
double num1, num2, result;
String sign = "";
```

You need to persist the values of these fields somewhere: ViewState would be one option.

A typical ViewState-backed property implementation would look something like:

```
public double Num1
{
    get
    {
        o = ViewState["Num1"];
        return (o == null) 0D : (double) o;
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["Num1"] = value;
    }
}
```

If you replace each of your fields num1, num2, result, sign with properties implemented like this (each with a unique name of course), and ViewState is enabled, then you should get the result you want.

Answer (score 2):

The `sign` variable is being reset to an empty string on post back by this line:

```
String sign = "";
```

You need to store the value of `sign` in cache so that it survives between post backs.

I recommend `Session` to do that, like this:

```
protected void minus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sign = "-";
    // Store sign in Session
    Session["theSign"] = sign;

    num1 = double.Parse(tb1.Text);
    tb1.Text = "";
}
```

---

> Note: Do this same `Session` storing logic in the other event handlers for `divide` and `product`.

---

Now in `Page_Load` you need to check the `Session` for the sign value every time, like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Default sign value that may be changed by value in session cache
    String sign = "";

    // Is there a session value for theSign
    if(Session["theSign"] != null)
    {
        // Yes, so set the sign variable value to use in click event handlers
        sign = Session["theSign"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: sign is globally accessible and as soon as i hit some button its value changes to the respective arithmetic sign

Comment: @Tahir - `sign` is a global variable that is being reset, see updated answer.